# extract list element names with NA using purrr::keep

Tags: r, purrr

I want to extract the `names` of elements that are `NA` in a list.

```
library(tidyverse)
mlist <- lst(p1 = data.frame(a = c(1, NA)),
            p2 = NA,
            p3 = data.frame(b = c(NA, "test")),
            p4 = NA,
            p5 = c(1, 2, NA))
mlist
# $p1
#    a
# 1  1
# 2 NA

# $p2
# [1] NA

# $p3
#      b
# 1 <NA>
# 2 test

# $p4
# [1] NA

# $p5
# [1]  1  2 NA
```

The easiest way to do this I found is using `base`:

```
names(mlist)[is.na(mlist)]
#[1] "p2" "p4"
```

But I had originally been trying to do this using `purrr::keep` and I'm still curious how to do it. I thought this would work:

```
map(mlist, ~keep(is.na(.))) %>% names()
```

any simple solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `keep` directly

```
library(purrr)
keep(mlist, ~ all(is.na(.x))) %>%
       names
#[1] "p2" "p4"
```

---

Or another option with pipe is

```
mlist %>%
     is.na %>% 
     which %>% 
     names
#[1] "p2" "p4"
```